# Messaging system. Multiple recipients, retrieving data. Best Practice

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

Messages:

```
id
message_text
..omitted..
```

Recipients

```
id
message_id
recipient_id
..omitted..
```

I would like to show in a table the message you sent, and whom you sent to.

```
to                        message        date

paul,roger,micheal        howdy          2011 12 12
paul                      hello          2011 12 12
paul,micheal              hi             2011 12 12
```

Obviously since there are multiple recipients, a join query will return x duplicate records for x number of recipients, grouping for id will return only the first recipient.

What is the best practice this case?
Should I make two separate queries (one for the message itself, one for the recipients)?
Are there alternatives?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(recipient_name) AS recipients,
  message_text AS message,
  date
FROM Messages JOIN Recipients ON Messages.id = Recipients.message_id
GROUP BY Recipients.message_id, message_text, date
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can accomplish this with a GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT (so all receipients will be concatanated in one field in the resultset)